# the xaml live previewer seems mirrored

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

hi there im coding an app with .net maui and the xaml live previewer seems mirrored ive arabic windows ui which means the buttuns should be on the other side and thats normal i changed that in appmanifest xaml and its put the buttuns in the right place in the app but the xaml live previewer still mirrored [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGyAg.png)

im trying to use xaml live privewer to edit the app in live easly thats all but its mirrored for no reason

Comment: OMG, that looks cool! (Sorry, I can't help!)

Comment: May I confirm that are you running the maui app on a Windows machine set to the `Arabic language`?

Comment: Yes I did that I went to app manifest to change the language but also didn't work I changed the whole system to English theme but also didn't work

Comment: @fethi Thanks for the update, you can set the `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"` in `ContentPage`  xaml to see if it works.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT its still the same  https://imgur.com/a/7YQozdS

Comment: @fethi It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)